# Plotting 3d dimensional histogarm in a spatial grid

Tags: visualization

Is there any tool to plot 3d dimensional histogram in a spatial grid? Preferably are there any filters or operators in Paraview or Visit for this?

Comment: When you say "3d histogram", do you mean something like a 3d plot where the histogram bins are in two-dimensions, and the vertical dimension is frequency, or do you mean that the bins are 3d, and frequency is represented in another fashion (represented by the size and color of a glyph, for example)?

Comment: If you mean the former (Geoff's question), then you can use [R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089752/r-generate-2d-histogram-from-raw-data), [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram3D.html), [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html), [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hist2d_log_demo.html) and many other tools. Virtually all similar tools with a programming language interface (as opposed to graphical interface) will have the functionality.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry sorry for not being clear but yes

Comment: @Szabolcs My data size is pretty huge around 8M cells, I am quite certain Mathematica cannot handle it, but I don't know about the rest.

Comment: @StephenJacob I'm pretty sure it can handle it, but you're right in that simply applying the builtin function I referenced might be too slow. But a custom function will handle it.

Comment: @StephenJacob If you tried using Mathematica and the problem was too big for it, feel free to post the challenge on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)  Just make sure you include some example data!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Paraview, you can be interested in do this task with Python. In Matplotlib you can do a [3D histogram](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) or a [3D bar](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html) plot.